# While pulling data from feed and transforming then getting Date conversion is not working

Tags: c#

We are getting some data from feed where date is something like "28-07-2020 09:11:57 AM" when i am trying to convert it it is always giving error that

**"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**

I have used many methods like Convert.ToDateTime, DateTIme.Parse , DateTime.parseExact but all are having same error.

string s = "28-07-2020 09:09:57 AM";
var dt=  DateTime.ParseExact(s,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime dt2= Convert.ToDateTime(s);

DateTime dt3=DateTime.Parse(s);

Can someone please suggest what is the issue in date format. We need to change it regardless culture as it is a window application and running on diff machines.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include examples of you using these methods? Also, if you're not specifying the culture explicitly when calling these methods, what is the [current culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_CurrentCulture) on the machine where the code is running?

Comment: None of them is going to work - this is a very strange custom format. You'll have to use `DateTime.ParseExact` with a pattern that matches this format. Are you sure the data shouldn't be *reversed*? The de-facto standard for date literals (ie strings) is the ISO8601 format. I'd expect any feed or HTTP API to return dates as `2020-07-28 09:11:57`, possibly with a timezone offset

Answer (score 0):

You were close, this works for me:

```
string s = "08-07-2020 09:09:57 AM"; 
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M-d-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note matching dashes instead of slashes in pattern.

Comment: Sorry but if date is changed to 28-07-2020 then it gives issue. i have edit my question

Answer (score 0):

After many try and combination below worked

string s = "28-07-2020 09:09:57 AM";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "d-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me (https://dotnetfiddle.net/MqwLLb):**

*Input:*

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "28-07-2020 09:09:57 AM";
        var dt= DateTime.ParseExact(s,"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        
        Console.WriteLine("dt => " + dt);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
dt => 7/28/2020 9:09:57 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1) method, it is quite useful if you are not sure about the incoming string value, also it is giving the result of parsing process as a boolean which makes easier to check if everything is right, and you can play with [DateTimeStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=netcore-3.1) for adjusting output.

```
 string s = "28-07-2020 09:09:57 AM";
 var dt = new DateTime();
 var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,out dt);
```